# MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification seems more reliable than MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification

Tags: ios4, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am streaming small movies (1-3MB) off my website into my iPhone app.  I have a slicehost webserver, I think it's a "500MB slice".  Not sure off the top of my head how this translates to bandwidth, but I can figure that out later.

My experience with MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification is not very good.
I get much more reliable results with the old MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification

If I get a MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification, the movie will play without stuttering, but if I use MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification, the movie frequently stalls.

I'm not sure which load state to check for:

enum {
   MPMovieLoadStateUnknown        = 0,
   MPMovieLoadStatePlayable       = 1 << 0,
   MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK  = 1 << 1,
   MPMovieLoadStateStalled        = 1 << 2,
};

MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK seems to be what I want (based on the description in the documentation):

```
MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK
  Enough data has been buffered for playback to continue uninterrupted.
  Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
```

but that load state NEVER gets set to this in my app.

Am I missing something?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm running into similar issues with this. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Just making sure that you noticed **it's a flag, not a value**?

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [aNotification object];
NSLog(@"LoadState: %i", (NSInteger)mp.loadState);

if (mp.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: OK thanks, I'll look into it again at some point.  Have you good experience with streaming?

Comment: Minor problems, but all the hard work is done at server side. Can't complain, HTTP Live Streaming is great so far :)

Comment: I had a count down for the video which is loaded from a web server. First I was using `MPMovieLoadStatePlayable` which lead to a time lag between the countdown and the video. Using `MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK` fixed this problem for me. Thanks